# How to obtain a diffeomorphism between $SL(2;\mathbb{C})$ and $S^{3}×\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups

By polar decomposition, we have that every $A \in SL(2;\mathbb{C})$ can be written uniquely as $A = Ue^{X}$, where $U \in SU(2)$ and $X$ is a self-adjoint matrix with trace zero. I already know that $SU(2)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^{3}$. Can someone give me a hint on how to obtain the diffeomorphism?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your question is why the polar decomposition is smooth?

Comment: Not really. As stated, I am trying to obtain a diffeomorphism and perhaps I could use the smoothness of the polar decomposition but I still don't know how.

Comment: What's the dimension of self-adjoint matrices of trace zero, as a real vector space ?

Comment: I think that the self-adjoint matrices are 2x2 with complex entries.